# Compare two php variables in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I'm struggling to compare two php variables to display or not display some text depending if the variables match or not. This is what I have:

```
<?php $link = the_permalink();?>
<?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'news' ) ); ?>
    <?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>                           
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('featured_companies')): ?>
            <?php $company = the_sub_field('featured_company'); ?>
            <?php  if ($link == $company) { ?>
                show news articles
            <?php } else { ?>
                don't show news articles
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

I want to compare `$link` and `$company` and if they match then do the stuff within the if. Where am I going wrong?

I'm using the http://www.advancedcustomfields.com plugin in Wordpress if that helps.

UPDATE:
Firstly forgot to mention that the two variables are urls. At the moment it's echoing out 2 urls that are the same on the page I want, but it's also echoing out "show news articles" when the 2 urls don't match.

Underneath the twitter profile - http://www.mediwales.com/v3/members/mediwales/ shows the same two urls. But when you goto this page http://www.mediwales.com/v3/members/3m/ it shows two different urls yet shows "show news articles".

Comment: It would be good to know what goes wrong, what happens when this code runs? etc...

Comment: is the `$company` a permalink?  is `$link = the_permalink();` in The Loop?

Comment: @JKirchartz Yep it is a permalink and is within the loop. This is the page I'm working on - http://www.mediwales.com/v3/members/mediwales/ it's the bit underneath the twitter profile.

Comment: @Rob that page seems to be working as expected, any examples of when it's broken?

Comment: @JKirchartz I just updated the question with a second link to show the urls are different yet it's still showing the "show news articles" snippet of text.

Comment: @JKirchartz Yep, still the same thing happening.

Comment: Consider using `echo` to those 2 variables in order to indicate the difference if exists (and I guess that there's a difference because after all it doesn't work as expected)

Comment: UPDATE: I got into the second link and it works perfect , try to delete your browser `cache` and refresh.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I tried clearing cache but it still is showing the same. I appears to work if you check the link ending in mediwales. If you check the link ending 3m then it shows it's not quite working.

Comment: From what I see now in the 2nd link those variables aren't equal. so the condition works just fine

Comment: @OfirBaruch Therefore the text on the 3m page should say "don't show news articles".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it:

```
<h2>Latest News</h2>    
<?php $link = get_the_title(); ?>
<?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'news' ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>  
    <?php $post_link = get_post_permalink(); ?>                        
        <?php  if (get_field('featured_companies') != "") { ?>
            <?php foreach(get_field('featured_companies') as $post): ?>
                <?php $company = get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?>
                <?php if ($company == $link) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $post_link; ?>">News item 1</a>
                <?php } ?> 
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to be careful with Wordpress's native functions:

`the_permalink()` **echoes out** the permalink (see [documentation examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink#Examples))

`get_permalink()` **returns** it as a variable (see [documentation examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_permalink#Examples))

So you need to be using:

```
$title = get_permalink();
```

Comment: Just tried that and now it's saying they both don't match on each page even though one does and the other doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure that get_permalink() is returning what you think it should be returning? Try echoing it out and using die(), just to see if it's delivering the string you want it to. If it's not, perhaps include the post's ID as the variable, or include it in a loop

Comment: Yep I have this line: <p>permalink of current page: <?php $link = get_permalink(); echo $link; ?></p>

Comment: Are you trying to compare the post's permalink with _same_ post's custom field called 'featured_company'? Or are you comparing _different_ posts?

Comment: Yes, the first part. So I can return all the news that has the member company selected.

Comment: Okay, well you need to place the line `$title = get_permalink();` inside the loop. Copy and paste it so that it's under `<?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>`

Comment: That will output it per news item as it's within a loop. I've tried everything but it's saying they're not matching even though they are. Is there a way I can just strip everything out bar the last part of the link (ie. mediwales or 3m) and try to match that. It seems that it doesn't like the link!

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to compare: you said you wanted to compare two fields in ONE post (i.e. in one news item), but now you say you don't want to do that. If you're trying to compare TWO news items, you need to include the post ID in anything outside the loop: `get_hyperlink($post_id)`